# How to create a neuronal network in machine learning to make statistics?

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, keras

I'm actually working on a machine learning project and I need to make some "previsions". 
[I have this datas (solar panel and kind of weather)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wQaQ.jpg)
I need to make a prevision of the energy efficiency of the following days.

I search a little bit on this, there is some informations about neuronal network like Keras. I install it but I just don't know how to make it works in my situation. I am beginer in machine learning, I learn a lot about this but it's a lot of theory and little practice so I'm really lost.

If there is someone who can just says me how can I do or give me something like a search trail !

Thanks a lot for the support !

Comment: I recommend you search for keras tutorials and tensorflow tutorials, start playing with some code, and ask again when you encounter problems

Comment: Hey, tanks for your reply. I tried some code and I played with Kereas, Theano but it's always the same things (something like that https://i.stack.imgur.com/euVdr.png) and I don't know how to evolve and use the keras network to my specific case !

Comment: The picture you attached is of the learning or "training" process. You first need to define exactly what it is your network will learn and what you want it to predict. Then you must have enough data to use in training it. Like I said you have to be much more specific to get a good answer.  For example, do you want to train a classification network that will output discrete categories? Or a regression that will output some value for efficiency like percentage? If you don't know, you still have a lot to learn about neural networks. If you do know, start there.

Comment: Yep it's trainning but I don't know how to use it to make what I want. As I said in the other reply : as you can see in my screen, I have the data the weather (in fact wind, irradiance, temperature, humidity and the rain) and also the production in energy of a photovoltaic panel. I have this data read every 20 seconds over 3 years. I want to predict the energy efficiency (PolyC energy in Wh) of tomorrow giving the weather. That's my project.

Comment: Then I again recommend using tensorflow tutorials to learn how to program a regression neural network. Turn your data into inputs for that network and try to make it output one number for efficiency. I can't be more specific than that without writing the code for you. You should ask questions here for specific problems in your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I'll try it and tell what's going on !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use keras/tensorflow or other libraries you need to know how to code in python at least and should have the understanding of neural networks. To begin with, you can have a look at knime (https://www.knime.org/) this provides similar functionalities but you need not do any coding. This might help you in understanding what's happening when you apply any kind of algorithm. Once you have a fair idea you might want to try to use keras/tensorflow.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know how to develop in python, this not a problem for me. My only one problem I think is the understanding of how, in
 practice, to use a neuronal network to  make previsions in a specific case.

Comment: By previsions you mean predictions?

Comment: Also can you tell me what you need to predict? To be specific which column in the data you want to predict? Because based on what you want to predict  you need to design and train your model.

Comment: Yes sorry "prediction". As you can see in my screen, I have the data the weather (in fact wind, irradiance, temperature, humidity and the rain) and also the production in energy of a photovoltaic panel. I have this data read every 20 seconds over 3 years. I want to predict the energy efficiency (PolyC energy in Wh) of tomorrow giving the weather.

Comment: Ok. Please try Liniear Regression to start with / DNN Regressor. As you have all the data you need and your have target data as well, this falls into supervised learning. Here PolyC energy in Wh is your target data and others are inputs.

Comment: Ok thank you verry much ! I'll try it asap and tell you what's going on !